# Pass variables one after other

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, automation, automated-tests, sh

I'm writing a shell script to pass variables to parameter store. I have variables in test.txt file like this

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

script:

```
first=$(cut -d'=' -f1 test.txt)
        second=$(cut -d'=' -f2 test.txt)
        for name in $first; do
        echo ""$name".integration"= $second
        done
```

I want to pass like this

a.integartion=1
b.integration=2

but i get the output like this

a.integration=1 2 3 ..   b.integration=1 2 3 ...

I have no idea how to change the script any suggestions

Comment: what are the contents of test.txt file. can you post any sample data in question?

Comment: test.txt has variables in it, like this a=1 b=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Should work like this:-

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
   first=`echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1`
   second=`echo $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
   echo ""$first".integration"=$second
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, man.  in output i receive space between words like a<space>.integration=1 b<space>.integration=2 so on. How can i remove that space

Comment: there wont be any space in output, if solution is correctly copy pasted. check your code if there is any space after `"$first"`.

Comment: I got that in my file had a = 1 so space is copied from file, i remove those thank you

Comment: Sorry, onemore when i replace echo line with {aws ssm put-parameter --name ""$first".integration" --type SecureString --value "$second"} only the first variable is uploading leaving all others, how do i add a loop? Is that possible

Comment: Also, you are quoting exactly the wrong expressions: `echo "$first.integration=$second"`.

Comment: when i use `while IFS== read -r first second;
do
   first=`echo $line | cut -d'!' -f1`
   second=`echo $line | cut -d'!' -f2`
   echo "$first.integration"="$second"
done < test.txt` it displays `.integration=`  only that one